# SED Replace after certain pattern - value in brackets

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have files where i need to replace all occourences of
`AC %blabla%` with `AC (%blabla%+PAR)`.

```
ROT: S 3    BL 3900   SPEED 20
    BEN: L 15   
         
ROT: S 2    BLL (DimZ/2+25) BLR (DimZ/2-29) SPEED 20                 
    BEN: L 14-0.5 A 116  AC -1
    
 ROT: S 2   BLR (DimZ/2-29) BLL (DimZ/2-20) SPEED 20                   
     CLA: L 133 A 64    AC -1 
     
ROT: S 1    BLL (DimZ/2-29) BLR (DimZ/2+25) SPEED 20        
    BEN: L 11-0.5  AC -90
    BEN: L 95   AC 1.5
```

E.g.:
`AC -1` should be `AC (-1+PAR)` afterwards.
`AC 90` should be `AC (90+PAR)` afterwards.

**What i've tried is:**

```
sed "s/\( AC"."\)/\1(/"
```

But that doesn't even always add the "("...
I get:

```
ROT: S 3    BL 3900   SPEED 20
    BEN: L 15   
         
ROT: S 2    BLL (DimZ/2+25) BLR (DimZ/2-29) SPEED 20                 
    BEN: L 14-0.5 A 116  AC (-1
    
 ROT: S 2   BLR (DimZ/2-29) BLL (DimZ/2-20) SPEED 20                   
     CLA: L 133 A 64    AC -1 
     
ROT: S 1    BLL (DimZ/2-29) BLR (DimZ/2+25) SPEED 20        
    BEN: L 11-0.5  AC (-90
    BEN: L 95   AC (1.5
```

Could someone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: The expected results are clear: *E.g.: `AC -1` should be `AC (-1+PAR)` afterwards. `AC 90` should be `AC (90+PAR)` afterwards.*

Comment: What `sed` version are you using? Is it GNU or FreeBSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following POSIX BRE compliant regex with `sed`:

```
sed "s/\( AC \)\([^[:space:]]*\)/\1(\2+PAR)/" file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/3gtAfp)

If you have GNU `sed`, I suggest

```
sed -E "s/\b(AC\s+)(\S+)/\1(\2+PAR)/" file
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/xmYpMU).

**Regex details**

- `\( AC \)` - Group 1: space, `AC`, space (so, no match for `BAC`, for example)
- `\([^[:space:]]*\)` - Group 2: zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\1(\2+PAR)` - the replacement is the concatenated Group 1 value + `(` + Group 2 value and `+PAR)`.

**GNU `sed` regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(AC\s+)` - Group 1: `AC` and one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/(AC )([^ ]*)/\1(\2+PAR)/' ip.txt
ROT: S 3    BL 3900   SPEED 20
    BEN: L 15   
         
ROT: S 2    BLL (DimZ/2+25) BLR (DimZ/2-29) SPEED 20                 
    BEN: L 14-0.5 A 116  AC (-1+PAR)
    
 ROT: S 2   BLR (DimZ/2-29) BLL (DimZ/2-20) SPEED 20                   
     CLA: L 133 A 64    AC (-1+PAR) 
     
ROT: S 1    BLL (DimZ/2-29) BLR (DimZ/2+25) SPEED 20        
    BEN: L 11-0.5  AC (-90+PAR)
    BEN: L 95   AC (1.5+PAR)
```

- `-E` to enable Extended Regular Expressions

  - Use `sed 's/\(AC \)\([^ ]*\)/\1(\2+PAR)/'` if `-E` isn't supported
- `(AC )` to match and capture `AC` followed by space

  - use `( AC )` to avoid partial match or use `\b(AC )` if word boundary is supported
- `([^ ]*)` to capture non-space characters
- `\1(\2+PAR)` required output format

---

What's wrong with OP's attempt:

- `"s/\( AC"."\)/\1(/"` will be treated as concatenation of `s/\( AC` followed by `.` followed  by `\)/\1(/`

  - can be simplified to `sed 's/\( AC.\)/\1(/'` --> use single quotes unless double is required
- `\( AC.\)` will match space followed by `AC` followed by any character **only once**
- `\1(` will give you captured portion followed by `(`